# Visual Basic List subdirectories in a directory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, directory

How can I do this? I tried doing looking in

```
My.Computer.Filesystem
```

and

```
FileIO.Filesystem
```

Comment: Please don't tag .NET questions with VBA - they're not related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("Directory Path");
```

This will return a String() (string array) of the subdirectories.

[Directory.GetDirectories Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories.aspx)

Note that there are 3 overloads for this method.  The first one (shown above) simply takes the supplied directory and lists subdirectories.

`GetDirectories(path, searchPattern)` takes the path and a search pattern (like "my*" - which would list all directories that start with "my").

`GetDirectories(path, searchPattern, searchOption)` is like the second one, but searchOption indicates whether or not to search subdirectories within the current directory.  Values are SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly or SearchOption.AllDirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` or `System.IO.Directory` class methods.